# Dynamic Variable of expected arrivals

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

Dear AnyLogic community,

Once again I have a question for more experienced AnyLogic model builders. In my current model I have various source blocks that each generate arrivals according to a unique weekly repeating schedule of "per hour" rates, given in hourly intervals.

I want to define a dynamic variable that tells me the expected number of arrivals over the next X hours - is this possible?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not by default. Either code a function that does it or code a ML model that "learns" from the past and predicts your future.

At the core, AnyLogic (and no other sim tool) provides you with build-in tools to peek into the future of the current model run. It would be a little pointless because running a sim model itself is already a virtual peek into the future. And what you want to do is to peek into the future while you peek into the future :-)

So for your simple problem, storngly suggest you just code it from the schedules that govern the sources, given thecurrent model time.

cheers